# C# UDP Socket not listening for responses?

Tags: c#, java, udp, client

I got a little problem with one of my programs.
Here is how it should work:

1. C# Client sends data to Java server
2. Java server checks the data
3. Java server send back commands to C# client
4. C# Client receives data and enables the user to login or register

I managed to get till step 3 but now I get stuck at step 4.

I ran Wireshark on the server and the client and the server.
All packages are coming in and out correctly.
The server receives one packet and gives one out.
The client gives one out and receives one.
However, if I check netstat in the console I see no open ports.
Actually I don't see any UDP sockets at all.
So the packet comes in but the C# client doesn't seem to listen, why?

Here is the C# client.

```
// Opening a socket with UDP as Protocol type
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
// The address of the server
IPAddress[] address = Dns.GetHostAddresses("192.168.0.87");
// The Endpoint with the port
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(address[0], 40001);

// Defining the values I want
string values = "Something I send here";
// Encoding to byte with UTF8
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(values);

// Sending the values to the server on port 40001
socket.SendTo(data, endPoint);

// Showing what we sent
Console.WriteLine("Sent: " + values);

// Timeout for later, for now I just let the program get stuck
// socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 5000);

// Allowing the response to come in from everywhere
EndPoint response = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
// Buffer for server response (currently bigger then actually necessary for debugging)
byte[] responseData = new byte[1024];

//Receiving the data from the server
socket.ReceiveFrom(responseData, ref response);

// Outputing what we got, we don't even get here
Console.WriteLine("You got: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseData));

// Closing the socket
socket.Close();
```

For debugging, if the user authenticated successfully I want to send the string "Test" back.

Here is the Java server

```
// Printing to the server that the user username logged in successfully
System.out.println("User " + username + " logged in succesfully!");

// The byte buffer for the response, for now just Test
byte[] responseData = "Test".getBytes("UTF-8");
// The Datagram Packet, getting IP from the received packet and port 40001
DatagramPacket responsePacket = new DatagramPacket(responseData, responseData.length, receivePacket.getAddress(), 40001);
// Sending the response, tried putting Thread.sleep here didn't help
serverSocket.send(responsePacket);
```

I expect that I did something wrong with the C# client at the receive part but not sure what, any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Usually you need to close off the socket once you have sent whatever you wanted to send. Have you tried closing `serverSocket`?

Comment: I think you are missing the call to Bind in the client code.

Comment: @nptini I can't access the socket after it is closed anymore but I also tried using UdpClient and a new socket, still didn't work.

Comment: @wolfcastle Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing the call to Bind on the client socket.

```
// Allowing the response to come in ON port 40001
EndPoint response = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 40001);

socket.Bind(response);  // bind to port 40001 on some local address
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the problem, but typically UDP responses are sent back to the originating (source) port of the original request. You are sending the response back to a fixed port. Can you try changing the Java bit to:

```
DatagramPacket responsePacket = new DatagramPacket(responseData, 
     responseData.length, receivePacket.getAddress(), receivePacket.getPort());
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! The error was on the C# part though, adding socket.Bind() worked just fine, Client is properly listening now.